# Hashing for array indices

Tags: c, hash

In my C program, I have four 8-bit (*char*) variables allocated in a structure. If I want to hash these numbers in order to create keys (representing the whole structures) which will index an array, how shall I do? (In the program there are many of these structures; since I often have to search in a symbol table to see whether they exist, if I don't want to create others, I haven't known which hashing algorithm to use, if I'd want to do a key-indexed search).

I've thought about a kind of hashing which takes the four numbers, turns them in hexadecimal numbers, puts them in succession, and then converts the number that comes out to a decimal number.

But I need something less "heavy"... this method seems too vain, and I think it's not so appropriate for creating array indices.

Is it? Is there another kind of hash functions, which also takes less memory than 32 bits, if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at this [list of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions).

For implementing a hash table (which is your goal I suppose) you'd want a hash function with [avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect) to avoid too many hash collisions for similar input values.

Of course, you could use any function to turn your characters into an arbitrary integer representation, but if this representation does not vary for different inputs you effectively have the performance of a linked list (imagine using one of the other suggestions with a table size of 256 and none of the structs varies on byte 4). What is your concern about 32-bit hashes? Of course you would use `hash%tablesize` for indexing?

Normally you wouldn't use a cryptographic hash function (e.g. md5, sha-1) either.  Just pick one of the non-cryptographic hash functions (e.g. Pearson/Jenkins hash).

```
/* jenkins hash, copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function */
uint32_t jenkins_one_at_a_time_hash(char *key, size_t len)
{
  uint32_t hash, i;
  for(hash = i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    hash += key[i];
    hash += (hash << 10);
    hash ^= (hash >> 6);
  }
  hash += (hash << 3);
  hash ^= (hash >> 11);
  hash += (hash << 15);
  return hash;
}
```

Side note: When you have a good hash value distribution, also make sure that the size of the hash table is large enough. You will observe performance to degrade as the occupancy (load factor) of the array approaches 1, because the likelihood of hash collisions will increase.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (that I don't think the OP is describing) would be to combine the 4 char values into a single 32-bit integer and then mod that with the size of the hash table (presumably a prime number):

```
unsigned int combined = (c1 << 24 ) | (c2 << 16 ) | (c3 << 8 ) | (c4);
unsigned int hashval = combined % hashtablesize;
```

It depends of course on the actual expected values for the 4 individual bytes, but this type of hash is reasonably efficient and typically has a good distribution.  It would be good to test the resulting hash values with an expected data set to make sure the distribution is somewhat even.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the structures in an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char a,b,c,d;
} item;
item items[20];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  items[0].a = 4;
  items[0].b = 6;
  items[0].c = 1;
  items[0].d = 3;
  // ...
  items[4].a = 12;
  // ...
  printf("%d %d %d %d\n", items[0].a, items[0].b, items[0].c, items[0].d);
  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this is the solution with less memory footprint, as the data is stored directly in the main array, so there is no need for hashing indexes, as the index of the array does the job with no memory consumption.

Of course you could use pointers, some C++ vector functionality, etc. But this is the most simple and efficient way.

The only caveat is that you must know the size of the array (how many items you will have) or a there-will-be-no-more-than-XXX maximum...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another kind of hash functions, which also takes less memory
>   than 32 bits, if it's possible?

This is an illusory issue.  The key is an array index -- it isn't stored anywhere, it's calculated on look-up.  Arrays in C are contiguous blocks, individual elements are accessed based on the start of the array and size of the type multiplied by the index.

For the key, just cast the value to an unsigned 32-bit type (don't just use `int` or `unsigned int` as the size is not necessarily 32-bits):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
char x[4] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
uint32_t *key = (uint32_t*)&x;
```

Then do modulus based on the table size.